# How do you access v-model input inside method?

Tags: vue.js

I'm very new to Vue.js and I can't figure out how to pass an input value to a method upon hitting enter so I can make an Axios request with it? I've tried the following but am getting "searchTerm is not defined".

Template:

```
<input v-on:keyup="hitEnter" v-model="searchTerm" type="text"/>
```

Data:

```
data () {
  return {
    searchTerm: ''
  }
}
```

Method:

```
hitEnter (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    console.log('Enter was hit' + searchTerm);
    var vm = this;
    axios.get('/api/search?q=' + searchTerm)
      .then(function (response) {
        vm.results = response.data.data;
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance on this.

Comment: You are missing the keyword`this`, should be `this.searchTerm`

Comment: That was it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @nunya Instead of having that if statement, use the enter modifier: `v-on:keyup.enter`.

Comment: Oh nice.  Thanks for sharing that tip.